# Relay variable number of arguments from one method to another with variable number of arguments

Tags: java

Say I have a public function `a()` and a private method `b()`. Both have variable number of parameters. `a()` needs to pass its parameters to a private function `b()`, which then converts the variable number of parameters to an EnumSet and passes it to `c()`.

```
public void a(MyEnum ... enums){
    // what code do I need here, to pass the parameters to b()?
}
private void b(MyEnum ... enums){
    for (int i = 0; i < enums.length; i++){
        // make EnumSet and pass it to c()
    }
}
private void c(EnumSet<MyEnum> enumSet){
}
```

How can I code `a()`?

Comment: Have you tried `b(enums);` what is `EnumSet` here? Try `c(Arrays.asList(enums));` and `private void c(List<MyEnum> enumSet){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [arbitrary number of arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) (called *varargs*) is a means to not manually create an array. Inside such a method *it is* an array.

And you can pass such an array as an argument to a vararg method:

```
public void a(MyEnum ... enums) {
    b(enums);
}
private void b(MyEnum ... enums) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b(enums);
```

Also, you could skip `b` alltogether and move the `for` loop to method `a`.